# How to move message to Folder in IMAP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, imap, message

I have folders

[image]

I want move message from INBOX to TRASH, but not working.
I try follow code:

```
$client->connect();
//Get all Mailboxes
/** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Support\FolderCollection $folders */
$folders = $client->getFolder('INBOX');
/** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Message $detail */
$detail = $folders->messages()->getMessageByUid($uid = $id);
// $detail->delete($expunge = true);
$message = $detail->move('TRASH');
 if ($message == true) {
      dd('Message has ben moved');
  } else {
      dd('False');
  }
```

But always return false.
Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For delete message or move to trash:

```
$oMessage = $oFolder->query()->getMessageByUid($uid);

$trash = 'INBOX/Trash';
$oFolder = $oClient->getFolder($trash, '/');
if (!$oFolder) {
   $trash = 'INBOX.Trash';
   $oClient->getFolder($trash, '.');
}

if ($request->folder == $trash) {
    $oMessage->delete();
} else {
    $oMessage->move($trash);
}
```